# How to use ListView in Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10 app)

Tags: listview, templates, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, uwp

Can anyone please explain `ItemTemplate.DataTemplate` and `ListView`. In this code snippet.
I really don't understand the concept of `Templates`, it will be help full if someone might put some light on that too.
I had look to this question:

[Metro app: ListView ItemTemplate DataTemplate for selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312058/metro-app-listview-itemtemplate-datatemplate-for-selected-item)

But still confused. 
Thank you!
:(

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text=", " />
                    <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 59):

ListView is a control that allows you to dynamically show a list of items so that users can scroll through that list of items to see them and find whatever they may need. It's really simple to define it in XAML:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="StudentsList" />
```

Now, let's say you have a list of university students. Every student is represented with a simple Student class.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

There could be dozens, hundreds or thousands of students, so you can't define the UI statically. You usually keep those students in some sort of list/collection in code-behind. You fetch them from various sources - database, web services, or hard-code it, like I will do now for demo purposes:

```cs
private List<Student> listOfStudents = new List<Student>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "John", Age = 20 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Bob", Age = 21 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Steve", Age = 19 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Marko", Age = 18 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Igor", Age = 20 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Ivan", Age = 20 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Nina", Age = 21 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Paul", Age = 20 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Ana", Age = 23 });
    listOfStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Ivana", Age = 20 });

    StudentsList.ItemsSource = listOfStudents;
}
```

That list/collection serves as an items source for the ListView, so you set the `ItemsSource` property of the ListView to connect the two and show the list in UI. Using a ListView all the items are rendered dynamically regardless of the number of items.

If we ran the app now, it would be pretty ugly though:

[image: Ugly ListView]

You need to define a `DataTemplate` to make it prettier. Since each and every student has a name and age, you will want to use those properties to make it look prettier. This `DataTemplate` is assigned to `ListView.ItemTemplate` property and the ListView will use it for each and every item in the list.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="StudentsList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           Margin="20,0,20,8"
                           FontSize="24" 
                           FontStyle="Italic" 
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                           Foreground="DarkBlue" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" 
                           Margin="20,0,20,8"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Foreground="DarkGray" 
                           Opacity="0.8" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

See, I used the DataTemplate to define which properties to show and how to render them - I played with font size, font colors, margins etc. I'll admit this isn't really that pretty, but I am sure you will get the point:

[image: A bit prettier ListView]

One more thing you'll notice is that I used a binding construct like this:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
```

This basically means: Check if the object has the property `Name` and if it does, render it as `TextBlock.Text`.

Note that things can get more complicated so you could use different templates for different items in one list etc. but that's not in the question scope I think.

TLDR: `ListView` dynamically renders a list of items. `ItemsSource` defines the items source for that `ListView`. `DataTemplate` defines a template that will be used to render something. This `DataTemplate` is assigned to `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListView` so that the `ListView` knows that it should use exactly that template to render its items.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Allot.

Comment: The name "MenuItem" does not exist in the namespace "using SoundDemo.Model".Is a very normal error I keep on getting and here I also do understand the error, If i reaname things and try resloving of the conflict still I can't resolve the problem. [Any suggestions on this part?]

Comment: ListView should be Scrollable which is not unfortunately by default.

Comment: Very good, easy example. I was doing the equivalent with UserControls and the performance was shocking!

Comment: Very good write-up helped me understand ListView and styling listview. thx

Comment: Very concise and very helpful. Will this only work in MainPage() or could I say for example have a button with a FileOpenPicker behind it, load in a text file and add data to the ListView?

Comment: Even at three years old this answer has helped gather an understanding of DataTemplates in UWP better than more recent articles.