# Style all ListViewItem in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal, listviewitem

I wanted to change the selected background color of an `ListViewItem`. Now I noticed, that the default value doesn't get overridden.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter
                  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                  SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                  CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                  CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                  DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                  DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                  FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                  FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                  PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                  PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
                  PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                  SelectedBackground="{StaticResource YellowBrush}"
                  SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
                  SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
                  PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
                  SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
                  DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                  DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                  ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  CheckMode="Inline"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705551/426227) it is mentioned, that one has to override the `ItemContainerStyle` property. But this can only be done on the `ListView` itself.

Is there no option to overwrite the style for all `ListViewItem` in the app?

PS: One could overwrite the brushes like e.g.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="Yellow" />
```

but I only want to style the `ListViewItem` and not affect other styles.

**Edit:**

Because I got

> Visual Studio requires a newer version of WIndows to display this content. Please update to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0.14393.0) or later.

I set the target version to 10240. This is what I found in the *App.xaml* after creating the copy as stated by Thomas Schneiter:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter 
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" 
                        ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        CheckMode="Inline"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                        CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" 
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}" 
                        FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" 
                        PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" 
                        PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                        PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" 
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                        SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" 
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" 
                        SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" 
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" 
                        SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I tried to override `SelectedBackground`, but the changes don't get applied.

Comment: Add a copy of `ItemContainerStyle` to your App.xaml Resources without a Key to make it the default for your application.

Comment: Can you post a link to a copy from `ItemContainerStyle`? I don't find one, except the [`ListViewItem` one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).

Comment: Seems you are using xamarin.form, and use xamarin's `ListView` control? Have you solve this problem?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT: Yes, that's right. No I haven't solved it. The following options comes to my mind: 1. Create a custom theme (seems hackish). 2. Create a custom renderer (but only for one platform?) 3. Try to overwrite events like `ItemSelected` and change the background color from there. But I would have to do this for every `ListView`. Ideally I could use a style like in the question, but the style isn't applied ...

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on any ListView in the Designer View and select `Edit Additional Templates` -> `Edit Generated Item Container (Item Container Style)` -> `Edit a Copy`.
Then select `Apply to all` and `Application` to automatically insert a global copy into the app.xaml.

Comment: Now I created the copy as you stated (see my edited question), but the style doesn't get applied. I believe it's because there was no `ItemContainerStyle` element be created?

Comment: If i change the `SelectedBackground` to another color it is applied to all my ListViews in the Application. The `ItemContainerStyle` property should be removed from your `ListView` to use the globally defined style.

Comment: Now I tried the example from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33346834/426227) and the background does get applied, but not in my real world application. I also tried to apply my intial style and here it also works. Perhaps a framework issue (Xamarin.Forms). Once I know more, I give you some infos.

Comment: With the `ItemContainerStyle` you define the surrounding container of the Listview item. The `DataTemplate` is to arrange your data inside of this container. Maybe the controls in your `DataTemplate` have a background color so you can't see the Background of the ItemContainer?

Comment: How can I lookup what's in the `DataTemplate’? Tree Visualizer?

Comment: Yes you can use the Live Visual Tree to see what's inside. The default DataTemplate for UWP is just a TextBlock. I never used Xamarin Forms so i'm not sure about that.

Comment: The structure for a XF UWP app (defaults) is the following: `ListViewItem` > `ListViewItemPresenter` > [`CellControl`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/c83c830c68bc0da08f330457dc6901f1657b86f5/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/CellControl.cs) > [`ContentPresenter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ContentPresenter.cs) > `StackPanel` > `TextBlock`. In a normal UWP app you only have `ListViewItem` > `ListViewItemPresenter` > `TextBlock`.

Comment: I can change `SelectedBackground` of `ListViewItemPresenter`. So it seems the background is taken from there. If I change the [`SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml#L292) globally, also the selected background changes. Still have no clue, why the style isn't applied ...