# Any similar "ListView" UI Control in Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.mac

I'm planning to design an multiple file downloader app (similar to IDM or Transmission) for macOS based on Aria2 JSON-RPC and C# GUI via Xamarin.Mac. But there is a major issue for UI design. I need a UI control which is similar to "ListView" in XAML.

Basically it's something like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339255/how-to-use-listview-in-universal-windows-platformwindows-10-app) discussed, i.e. I need something equivalent in Xamarin.Mac with this XAML code below:

```
<ListView x:Name="DownloadItemList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DownloadItemTitle}" 
                           Margin="20,0,20,8"
                           FontSize="24" 
                           FontStyle="Italic" 
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                           Foreground="DarkBlue" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DownloadProgressInfo}" 
                           Margin="20,0,20,8"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Foreground="DarkGray" 
                           Opacity="0.8" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I also need some data bindings in the UI code if possible. But so far I can't find any similar stuff in Xamarin.Mac. Is there any possible solution like this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html)

**static Content** : 
You can design cells from storyboard, and if required can modify content of these cells at runtime.

**Dynamic Content**  : You can crate template cell at design time (or progrmmatically id requried ), give it identifier and use that cell multiple-time in [tableviewd atasource](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-tableviews/#Populating_the_Table_View).

Comment: UITableView is iOS only. NSTableVIew is for Cocoa (the question has both tags).

Comment: @ChrisHamons Thanks for correction.Have corrected it now.

Comment: It should work though it seems very complex for me. Thanks mate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like a table view

Hope this helps.

[Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-tableviews/)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest table view. I'd only recommended this for presenting static data.

Comment: If you want to use tableview here's a sample in C# - https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples/tree/master/NSOutlineViewAndTableView